# Pass a function that returns the value of the ko.computed

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have two functions `generate` and `test`. When the user clicks a button `generate` is called which then calls `test` function. I receive the following error:

> Pass a function that returns the value of the ko.computed.

The error is thrown on this line in the test function.:

```
var unmapped = ko.mapping.toJS(this);
```

`this` is my viewmodel with ko.observable properties.

Here are the two functions. If I move the content of `test` function to `generate` everything works fine but I need the logic to be in two different functions. What can I do?

I am very stuck here. Any help will be greatly apreciated.

```
generate = function () {
            if (!omega.validatableFranchiseGeneration.validate()) {
                return false;
            }
            omega.franchiseInfo.IsForGeneration(true);

            test();
        }

 var test = function () {
        getIpsAndPorts();

        for (var i = 0; i < omega.franchiseInfo.LanguagesInfoViewModel().length; i++) {
            if ($.isArray(omega.franchiseInfo.LanguagesInfoViewModel()[i].SubMenuItemsViewModel)) {
                omega.franchiseInfo.LanguagesInfoViewModel()[i].SubMenuItemsViewModel = omega.franchiseInfo.LanguagesInfoViewModel()[i].SubMenuItemsViewModel[0];
            }
        }

        var unmapped = ko.mapping.toJS(this);

        var jsonData = ko.toJSON(unmapped);
        $.ajax({
            url: "/franchise/Save",
            type: "POST",
            // data: ko.toJSON({ folderName: FolderName }),
            data: { franchiseInfoViewModel: jsonData },
            //traditional: true,
            //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                window.location.href = data.redirectToUrl;
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                jsonValue = jQuery.parseJSON(request.responseText);
                omega.franchiseInfo.errorMessages([]);
                for (var i = 0; i < jsonValue.errorMessages.length; i++) {
                    omega.franchiseInfo.errorMessages.push({ errorMessage: ko.observable(jsonValue.errorMessages[i].ErrorMessage) });
                }
                for (var i = 0; i < omega.franchiseInfo.LanguagesInfoViewModel().length; i++) {
                    InitializeViewLanguagesInfo(omega.franchiseInfo.LanguagesInfoViewModel()[i]);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing all your code this is hard to be sure, but if the code (as is) works when directly included in generate, then I'd be willing to bet that `this` is not what you think it is in the `test` function.  `this` has a different meaning inside the `test` function than it did inside `generate`.

Fire up Chrome or Firebug and set a breakpoint on the `var unmapped = ko.mapping.toJS(this);` line.  Run your program and when the breakpoint hits go to the Console and look at `this`.  Is it your ViewModel?

If `this` is what you expect inside `generate` you could always call `test` like this:

```
test.apply(this);
```

This will explicitly set the context of `this` for the method invocation.

Another option is to set a `self` variable inside your ViewModel.  This is usually done at the top and looks like: `var self = this;`.  By creating this variable you can then reference `self' inside any functions within the outer "function" scope, and not have to worry about the value of`this` fluctuating.

--

Here is a simple fiddle to simulate what I think is happening: http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/aLFWe/

Open Chrome or Firebug console and look at the logged objects.  Note that `Window` was the logged object when I just called `updatea()`, but was `Object` in the original click function and when I called `updateb.apply(this)` or `updatec()` (which referenced `self`).

Comment: Thank You for your answer. I refactored my logic and moved to a different solution. Nevertheless I am accepting your answer.